# Button not appearing on Scene and appearing on Top Left hand corner

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

```
@objc func buttonRoundPlayer(){
    
    buttonRound.setTitle("PlayerControl", for: .normal)
    buttonRound.addTarget(self, action: #selector(roundhandle), for: .touchUpInside)
    buttonRound.backgroundColor = .clear
    buttonRound.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    buttonRound.layer.borderWidth = 1
    buttonRound.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    buttonRound.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width + 260, y: 260, width: 50, height: 50)
    self.view!.addSubview(buttonRound)
    
}
```

The button doesn't appear on the scene unless self.view!.addSubview(buttonRound) and CGRect doesn't seem to affect the button's position and the button appears on the top left hand corner and no changes seems to affect the button position.

I was hoping to get some help in this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Button will never appear unless you call `addSubview`, this is the method that adds button as subview to view, if you dont call it then, how do you expect the button to appear on view? in iOS we rarely use hardcoded frame values to set the frame of button, we use autolayout predominantly else auto resizing (older iOS versions), doesnt frame work? It does but not something that is commonly used. but you are setting frame wrong, self.frame.width + 260 will add button 260 points outside the frame of view, how do you expect that button to appear or  take touch? What r u trying to do here?

Comment: Thank you and I'm trying to add the button to my current scene and on top have the ability to pick the position where the button should be located within my scene and not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call this function in `viewDidLoad()` then `self.frame` may be just an empty rect. Frame calculations are best done in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.

But in general, it’s better to use auto layout. For example:

```swift
buttonRound.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
buttonRound.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
buttonRound.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

For more info the Apple's [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) or search for the many tutorials available.

Comment: With auto layout how can I code the position I need the button to be in. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @OptiCode22, I added an example of using auto layout to place the button in the center. There are many other options, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I got error saying it wouldn't run and causes error

Comment: If you copy the error text, I may be able to help.